Does the order of the columns in the partition key matter?
Considering the table below, does the order of the partition key a and b matter?
CREATE TABLE t (
  a varchar,
  b int,
  c text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((a,b))
);

If a have more unique elements, should it be in the first or last position?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

The partition key as a whole uniquely identifies a partition in the cluster and gets hashed into a single token value regardless of how many columns there are in the composite partition key.
How the columns are ordered does not matter since all columns are required to identify a single partition. Cheers!
